# Automatically version font files to bust cache

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

We have a font file that holds all of our icons. As it stands now, if we add an icon to our font file our user won't see it until their cache expires or they clear cache and refresh (ctrl+F5) something our users are unlikely to know how to do.

Even if we turn off the caching, a simple refresh (F5) is required to get the latest. Something our users might do, but we know we'll get at least a few questions.

Ideally we'd cache the font files indefinitely and only download it again when something changes. Similar to how javascript and css files work with Asp.Net's bundling.

Is there a way to do this automatically? I found that if I had a `?v=1` to the end of the location of the font file in the @font-face of the CSS it does download the font file again, but it's a manual process and I'd like to avoid that.

Is there any way to automatically update the version query string of the font file in the CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really the answer I was looking for, but it is what I settled on doing. If you have a better solution please let me know I would love to mark something else as the answer :)

The behavior I described above for "turn off the cache" was actually not sending any cache header. If instead I send a `Cache-Control: no-cache` header the browser requests the font file on every page load. That request includes an eTag, so if the font file hasn't been modified the server sends a 304 and the browser pulls the font from it's cache.

The best part is that the page does not wait for the font file, it just does it's best until the server either returns a new font file or the 304.

That request is going to be wasted 99.99% of the time, but this app is an Single Page App, so it only makes that font request when first loading the app.